# Cannot enable gdm on debian 10

Tags: debian, systemd, gnome

I installed Gnome but cannot activate gdm service. Lightdm just works well but

```
sudo systemctl enable gdm3
```

returns:
**   Synchronizing state of gdm3.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gdm3
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
.wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
instance name specified.
**

Have been tried re-installing, checking up config file. And set graphical.target to user's default.